# Using onFocus/onClick to trigger a function within an input field in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, onfocus

OK so I have an input field that whose value is pre-loaded when the component mounts (this.state.color) and I'm attempting to add a handleColorPicker() function either onClick or onFocus that will dropdown a color picker from https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/. I'll paste the relevant code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ChromePicker } from 'react-color';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       color: 'FFFFFF',
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleColorPicker = this.handleColorPicker.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  }

  handleColorPicker(){
    console.log('open');
    return( 
      <ChromePicker />
    )
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <input
        className="App-textForm"
        type="text"
        name="color"
        value={this.state.color}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onClick={this.handleColorPicker}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

As constructed, it console.logs 'open' every time I click on it.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing as to why that onClick wouldn't trigger the ChromePicker? I've tried changing onClick to onFocus and have tried wrapping my input in a div with an onClick={this.handleColorPicker}. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not rendering the picker, you are just returning it and then doing nothing with it.

What you need to do is render the picker, you can do that by using the state and hide/show the picker based on the user selection. For example:

```
state = {
  showPicker: false,
};

handleColorPicker(){
  console.log('open');
  this.setState(current => ({
    showPicker: !current.showPicker, // <-- Toggle the state
  }));
}

render() {
  const { showPicker } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
    <input
      className="App-textForm"
      type="text"
      name="color"
      value={this.state.color}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      onFocus={this.handleColorPicker} // <--- Open the picker on focus
      onBlur={this.handleColorPicker}  // <--- Hide it on blur? You need to define when to hide it
     />
     { showPicker && <ChromePicker /> }
   </div>
 );
}
```

using `onFocus` and `onBlur` the state change and the picker gets renderer or not, based on the value of `showPicker`.

You need to define when to hide it, `onBlur` might not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`onClick` event `listener` doesn't do anything with the returned component. You need to set a state the renders the component conditionally like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ChromePicker } from 'react-color';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       color: 'FFFFFF',
       isColorPickerOpen: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleColorPicker = this.handleColorPicker.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  }

  handleColorPicker(){
    console.log('open');
    this.setState({ isColorPickerOpen: true });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
      <input
        className="App-textForm"
        type="text"
        name="color"
        value={this.state.color}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onClick={this.handleColorPicker}
      />
      {isColorPickerOpen?  <ChromePicker /> : null}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching your `handleColorPicker` to run correctly, but you shouldn't be returning the `ChromePicker` in that function.

Take a look at this [CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/o72031856q).

Notice how I have state in my component (`isColorPickerOpen`) that keeps track of whether the color picker is showing or not. My click handler toggles this state between true and false.

Then in my `render` method, I only render the `ChromePicker` component when `isColorPickerOpen` is true.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you are not rendering the `<ChromePicker />`

try this

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       color: 'FFFFFF',
       isPickerActive: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleColorPicker = this.handleColorPicker.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  }

  handleColorPicker(){
    this.setState({isPickerActive: true});
  }

  render() {
    return(
    <div>
      <input
        className="App-textForm"
        type="text"
        name="color"
        value={this.state.color}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onClick={this.handleColorPicker}
      />
      {this.state.isPickerActive && <ChromePicker />}
    <div>
    );
  }
}
```

But it will just open the picker. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

With the onClick you are not render ChromePicker when it return.

Instead you can have an state to handle the ChromePicker render. Every time that you click or focus on you input, you can change the state, and then the component will be re render again.

Example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ChromePicker } from 'react-color';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       color: 'FFFFFF',
       showChromePicker: false,
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleColorPicker = this.handleColorPicker.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  }

  handleColorPicker(){
    console.log('open');

    this.setState({
      showChromePicker: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { showChromePicker } = this.state;

    return(
      <div>
        <input
        className="App-textForm"
        type="text"
        name="color"
        value={this.state.color}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onClick={this.handleColorPicker}
        />
        {showChromePicker ? <ChromePicker /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```